# How many graphics card can x2 700 W power supply run?

Tags: power-supply, gpu

I recently built a computer for mining and, I am using a 700w PSU ( RADIX VII AG 700W TACENS TAC700RVIISILVER ) powering my motherboard and a gtx 1080 ti.

I was wondering if I add another one I mean ( 700w or 750w PSU) how many graphics card they both could run, more specifically how many GTX 1070's?

And can I use this [8 pin to dual PCI-E PCI Express 8pin ( 6+2 pin ) adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQLY5.png) to power multiple graphics cards since the power supply comes only with 2x PCI-E 8 pins ?

Thanks

Comment: Computers are rubbish at mining, the dirt clogs up the fans and they can't hold a pick axe.

Comment: [Power supply wattage math applied to videcards?](//superuser.com/q/289052)

Comment: You might find the answers [here](https://superuser.com/q/730481/117590) interesting for calculating GPU power requirements.

Comment: Ultimately it depends on how much power you're already using and how much the 1070 would use each. That might vary a lot and in addition you might take measures like undervolting to lower the consumption. Though I have to wonder why you chose a 1080 TI if your machine was build for mining?

Comment: Oh and for your adapter it would depend on the power rating of the corresponding rail.

Comment: I chose an 1080 TI because It will keep mining for a long time and mainly cuz I got it with a good price